# Relationship between strut and baselineskip

Tags: vertical-alignment, baseline, calc, strut

[Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts), it is said that a `strut` is defined as:

```
\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}
```

However, if I do:

```
\newlength{\strutheight}
\settoheight{\strutheight}{\strut}\printlength{\strutheight}
\printlength{\baselineskip}
```

It prints:

```
8.39996pt 12.0pt
```

`8.39996` is equal to `0.7*12`. However, what I don't understand is that according to its definition the height of the strut should be `\baselineskip`, because `-.3\baselineskip` only refers to a vertical alignment offset. Why does `\settoheight` on a `\strut` produces this behaviour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The height of the *whole* `\strut` is `\baselineskip`, however it is lowered by `0.3\baselineskip` form the baseline. Its depth plus its height totals `\baselineskip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\strutheight}
\newlength{\strutdepth}
\settoheight{\strutheight}{\strut}
\settodepth{\strutdepth}{\strut}
$\the\strutheight+\the\strutdepth=\the\baselineskip$
\end{document}
```

this prints `8.39996pt + 3.60004pt = 12.0pt`.

In TeX, the “height” of a box is not its total height, but the height above the baseline, and the “depth” is the amount that box goes below that baseline. And when you do `\settoheight` you get only the height of the box, not the total height.

You can draw the `\strut` and its height and depth to see:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep0pt
\fboxrule0.1pt

\fbox{\strut}
\fbox{\rule{0pt}{0.7\baselineskip}}
\fbox{\rule[-0.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{0.3\baselineskip}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, the definition of `\strut` is

```latex
% latex.ltx, line 594:
\def\strut{\relax\ifmmode\copy\strutbox\else\unhcopy\strutbox\fi}
```

The code `\rule[-0.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}` is a less efficient way to say `\unhcopy\strutbox`, but amounts to essentially the same. Part of the strut is *below* the baseline, to cope with characters with descenders like `p` or `y`.

The `\strutbox` is updated whenever a `\fontsize` command is processed:

```latex
% latex.ltx, line 2808:
\def\set@fontsize#1#2#3{%
    \@defaultunits\@tempdimb#2pt\relax\@nnil
    \edef\f@size{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
    \@defaultunits\@tempskipa#3pt\relax\@nnil
    \edef\f@baselineskip{\the\@tempskipa}%
    \edef\f@linespread{#1}%
    \let\baselinestretch\f@linespread
      \def\size@update{%
        \baselineskip\f@baselineskip\relax
        \baselineskip\f@linespread\baselineskip
        \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip
        \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
          \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
                \@depth.3\baselineskip
                \@width\z@}%
        \let\size@update\relax}%
  }
```

So the `\strutbox` is a box containing a zero width rule, with height 70% of the baseline skip and depth 30% of the baseline skip.

You can access the current dimensions as `\ht\strutbox` and `\dp\strutbox`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\the\ht\strutbox\ (height)

\the\dp\strutbox\ (depth)

\the\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox\ (total)

\the\baselineskip\ (baselineskip)

\end{document}
```

[image]